# parse grep output and run vim with result

Tags: vim, grep, string-parsing

I'm current using command line to grep a pattern in a source tree.  A line of grep output is in the form:

```
path/to/a/file.java:123: some text here
```

If I want to open the file at the location specified in the grep output, I would have to manually enter the vim command as:

```
$ vim +123 path/to/a/file.java
```

Is there an easier method that would allow me to use the raw grep output and have the relevant components parsed and run vim for the file at the line#.

I am interested in a command line solution.  I am aware that I can do greps inside vim.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You can use `system` function to run a grep and use vimscript to get the number and use it with `e` command. Or, the other way is to print the output of system(grep) command in the same file itself and then using a function and mapping to go to that file. In both the case, you have to open vim with or without a file and then run the commands/functions inside it.

Answer (score 2):

The [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) plugin is exactly what you want. With that installed, you can just run

```
vim path/to/a/file.java:123
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Even thought I did not specifically ask for a plugin. Thanks

Comment: @bzb If that was the answer you were looking for, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply run `grep` from Vim itself and benefit from the quickfix list/window:

```
:grep -Rn foo **/*.h
:cw
(scroll around)
<CR>
```

**Or** you could pass your `grep` output to Vim for the same benefits:

```
$ vim -q <(grep -Rn foo **/*.h)
:cw
(scroll around)
<CR>
```

**Or**, if you are already in Vim, you could insert the output of your `grep` in a buffer and use `gF` to jump to the right line of the right file:

```
:r !grep -Rn foo **/*.h
(scroll around)
gF
```

**Or**, from your shell:

```
$ vim <(grep -Rn foo **/*.h)
(scroll around)
gF
```

**Or**, if you just ran your `grep`, you can reuse it like so:

```
$ vim <(!!)
(scroll around)
gF
```

**Or**, if you know its number in `history`:

```
$ vim <(!884)
(scroll around)
gF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> vim $(cat the.file | grep xxx)
```

will evauluates the $() - find xxx in the.file then will pipe xxx to vim

also possible with backticks ``:

```
> vim `cat the.file | grep xxx`
```

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for.  I already have the grep output containing the line# of interest.  I just need a way to open the given file at the given line#.

Comment: Also, on another note, there is [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). You could avoid that in future...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -nr --null pattern | { IFS= read -rd "" f; IFS=: read -d "" n match; vim +$n "$f" </dev/tty; }
```

`grep` does a recursive search for `pattern`.  For the first file that it finds, `vim` is started with the `+linenum` parameter to put you on the line of interest.

This approach uses NUL-separated i/o.  It should be safe for all file names, even ones that contain white space or other difficult characters.

This was tested on GNU tools (Linux).  It may work on BSD/OSX as well.

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
grep -nr --null pattern | {
   IFS= read -rd "" f
   IFS=: read -d "" n match
   vim +$n "$f" </dev/tty
}
```

#### Convenience function

Because the above command is long, one may want to put it in a shell function:

```
vigrep() { grep -nr --null "$1" | { IFS= read -rd "" f; IFS=: read -d "" n match; vim +$n "$f" </dev/tty; }; }
```

Once this has been defined, it can be used to search for a file containing any pattern.  For example:

```
vigrep 'some text here'
```

To make the definition of `vigrep` permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### How it works

- `grep -nr --null pattern`

  `-r` tells grep to search recursively.

  `-n` tells grep to return line number of the matches.

  `-null` tells grep to use NUL-separated output

  `pattern` is the regex to search for.
- `IFS= read -rd "" f`

  This reads the first NUL-separated section of input (which will be a file name) and assigns it to the shell variable `f`.
- `IFS=: read -d "" n match`

  This reads the next NUL-separated section of input using `:` as the word separator.  The first word (which is the line number) is assigned to shell variable `n`.  The rest of this line will be ignored.
- `vim +$n "$f" </dev/tty`

  This starts `vim` on line number `$n` of file `$f` using the terminal, `/dev/tty`, for input.

  Generally, when running `vim`, one really wants to have `vim` accept input from the keyboard.  That is why, for this case, we hard-coded input from `/dev/tty`.

### Using cut-and-paste to launch vim

Start the following and cut-and-paste a line of `grep -n` output to it:

```
IFS=: read f n rest; vim +$n "$f"
```

The `read` command will wait for a line on standard input.  The type of input it expects looks like:

```
path/to/a/file.java:123: some text here
```

Because `IFS=:`, it divides up the line on colons and assigns the file name to shell variable `f` and the line number to shell variable `n`.  When this is done, it launches the `vim` command.

This command could also, if desired, be saved as a shell function:

```
grvim() { IFS=: read f n rest; vim "+$n" "$f"; }
```

Comment: This solves part of my issue.  I already have a list of grep outputs.  What I want is the ability quickly open the appropriate file using copy and paste of an already exising grep output. There is an issue with this solution in that it only opens the first file encountered.  The pattern could exist in multiple files

Comment: @bzb OK.  I added a cut-and-paste solution.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
grep_edit(){
    grep "$@" | sed 's/:/ +/;s/:/ /';
}
```

So, the output is in the form:

```
path/to/a/file.java +123 some text here
```

Then I can directly use

```
$ vi path/to/a/file.java +123
```

---

Note: I have also heard of [file-line plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39239141/793796), but I was not sure how it will work with `netrw` plugin.

e.g. vi can open remote files with this syntax:

```
vi scp://root@remote-system//var/log/daemon.log
```

But if that is not a concern, then you can better use file-line plugin.